# MSBuild in Visual Studio 2017: Cannot set path within Command Prompt

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to have MSBuild for Visual Studio 2017 run in my PATH on Windows 10.  I recently completed this task on another machine that was using Visual Studio 2015 no problem using this command:

```
"%comspec% /k""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat""
```

I noticed that for Visual Studio 2017, `VsMSBuildCmd.bat` is within **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools**

So I tried running the `%comspec%` command above with this folder but it's not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do mean "but it`s not working" ? Do you get error messages? Where you run this command? Could you please provide me some detail steps so that I could reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get MSBuild up and running even after I typed the `comspec` statement above with the error appearing my command prompt.  I'm not really sure if that is a Windows 10 bug.